# How come my outlook add-in only works once?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Ok so I have generated a very simple Ribbon to be added to each new Compose window that a user opens. The ribbon works fine the first time. It has 2 checkboxes on it, lets say the user selects the first checkbox and sends their message.

If I debug the code when the user sends their first message. In the `ItemSend` event I access `Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.MyCheckbox1.Checked` it will show that checkbox is checked. That window closes and the user opens a new email.

Lets say that in the second email the user clicks the second checkbox `Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.MyCheckbox2.Checked`. If I debug the same `ItemSend` event and look at that field it shows it as false and the the first checkbox is currently checked.

It is almost as if the `Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon` control instances aren't getting updated properly or if I am misunderstanding its not getting disposed of properly.

**Edit 1**

As an update I used the Ribbon (Visual Designer) to create my ribbon. Should I have used the Ribbon (XML)?

**Edit 2**

Not sure how adding this to my question, when it is already in the original question above makes any difference but here is my "code" that I used in the application.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    this.Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
}

void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel) {
    if (Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.MyCheckbox1.Checked) {

    } else { 

    }
}
```

Comment: We can't fix this without seeing your code.

Comment: .....I dont think code is going to help you here.

Comment: I'm not the one who needs help :)

Comment: Nice one! Does the question not suffice enough code to explain whats happening here? Did you try to create a new Outlook add-in project and test it with adding a simple checkbox and see if the behavior performs the same?

Comment: I've got some code on my computer that fixes your problem. Try using that to fix your problem.

Comment: Of course I didn't.  Please read the FAQ and look at the section on asking good questions.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was that I wasn't accessing the current ribbon collection. As the code states above I was using `Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.Checkbox1.Checked`. For each `ItemSend` event you need to specify `ThisRibbonCollection ribbonCollection = Globals.Ribbons[Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector()];` in order to get the current windows ribbon. This in turn gave me the correct values on the send event.

For those that need this in a code window.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    this.Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
}

void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel) {
    ThisRibbonCollection ribbonCollection = Globals.Ribbons[Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector()];
    if (ribbonCollection.MyRibbon.MyCheckbox1.Checked) {

    } else { 

    }
}
```